# How can I save bacillus strains on filter paper without an -80 degree freezer?

Tags: molecular-biology, bacteriology, lab-techniques

I want to save my bacillus strains but I don't have access to a -80 degree freezer.  What are possible alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Use agar stubs: pour some Nutrient agar (or any suitable agar medium) in a test tube (~10% of the tube volume) and punch your inoculum halfway into it using a pipette tip or inoculation loop. Store it in 4⁰C.

Glycerol stocks can be made and stored in -20⁰C also.

Comment: How long can you store them in agar stubs? Also we use -70 to -80°C to store our glycerol stocks.

Comment: I had stored them for a couple of months but i think it can withstand one more month..